# Не происходит переключение событий jQuery? Не происходит повторный выбор условия

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Никак не могу понять в чем я ошибаюсь.
Есть 3 ссылки и есть обработчик события, который срабатывает при клике на одну из 3-х ссылок.

Когда кликаю первый раз на ссылку - все работает как и должно. Но при клике на вторую ссылку - ничего не происходит! Как будто бы первая ссылка зафиксировалась и не отдает событие другим элементам.

При перезагрузке страницы - кликаю на вторую ссылку - всё работает, при клике на любую другую - опять не работает.
Получается, что срабатывает скрипт один раз, повторно не работает..

В чем проблема??? Уже всю голову сломал.

```js
let colorsClass1 = ['active-green', 'active-blue', 'active-violet'];
let colorsClass2 = ['active-crimson', 'active-magenta', 'active-navy'];
let colorsClass3 = ['active-coral', 'active-chartreuse', 'active-teal'];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.block--left-item').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('link-1')) {
      $('.block--left-item').removeClass();
      $('.block--left-list a').removeClass();

      const randomClassname1 = randClass1();
      $(this).addClass('block--left-item').addClass('link-1');
      $('.block--left-item a').addClass('link-1').addClass(randomClassname1);
      $('.logo-svg').removeClass().addClass(randomClassname1 + ' logo-svg');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('link-2')) {
      $('.block--left-item').removeClass();
      $('.block--left-list a').removeClass();

      const randomClassname2 = randClass2();
      $(this).addClass('block--left-item').addClass('link-2');
      $('.block--left-item a').addClass('link-2').addClass(randomClassname2);
      $('.logo-svg').removeClass().addClass(randomClassname2 + ' logo-svg');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('link-3')) {
      $('.block--left-item').removeClass();
      $('.block--left-list a').removeClass();

      const randomClassname3 = randClass3();
      $(this).addClass('block--left-item').addClass('link-3');
      $('.block--left-item a').addClass('link-3').addClass(randomClassname3);
      $('.logo-svg').removeClass().addClass(randomClassname3 + ' logo-svg');
    }
  });
});


//Функция рандомного класса из массива

function randClass1() {
  let randomClass1 = colorsClass1[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsClass1.length)];
  return randomClass1;
};

function randClass2() {
  let randomClass2 = colorsClass2[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsClass2.length)];
  return randomClass2;
};

function randClass3() {
  let randomClass3 = colorsClass3[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsClass3.length)];
  return randomClass3;
};
```

```css
body, ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1170px;
}

.block--left-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.block--left-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation a {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.block--left {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.swiper-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 585px;
}

.block--right {
  position: relative;
}

.block--right a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.active-black {
  color: black;
}

/* Цвета для первой ссылки*/

.active-green {
  color: yellowgreen;
}
.active-blue {
  color: aqua;
}
.active-violet {
  color: darkmagenta;
}

.logo-svg.active-green {
  fill: yellowgreen;
}
.logo-svg.active-blue {
  fill: aqua;
}
.logo-svg.active-violet {
  fill: darkmagenta;
}

/* Цвета для второй ссылки*/

.active-crimson {
  color: crimson;
}
.active-magenta {
  color: magenta;
}
.active-navy {
  color: navy;
}

.logo-svg.active-crimson {
  fill: crimson;
}
.logo-svg.active-magenta {
  fill: magenta;
}
.logo-svg.active-navy {
  fill: navy;
}

/* Цвета для третьей ссылки*/

.active-coral {
  color: coral;
}
.active-chartreuse {
  color: chartreuse;
}
.active-teal {
  color: teal;
}

.logo-svg.active-coral {
  fill: coral;
}
.logo-svg.active-chartreuse {
  fill: chartreuse;
}
.logo-svg.active-teal {
  fill: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="block--left-list">
          <li class="block--left-item link-1">
            <a href="#">отделка</a>
          </li>
          <li class="block--left-item link-2">
            <a href="#">архитектура</a>
          </li>
          <li class="block--left-item link-3">
            <a href="#">планировки</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в функции. Забыл добавить нужны классы, поэтому в условия не происходил заход.

```js
let colorsClass1 = ['active-green', 'active-blue', 'active-violet'];
let colorsClass2 = ['active-crimson', 'active-magenta', 'active-navy'];
let colorsClass3 = ['active-coral', 'active-chartreuse', 'active-teal'];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.block--left-item').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('link-1')) {
      $('.block--left-item').removeClass();
      $('.block--left-list a').removeClass();

      const randomClassname1 = randClass1();
      $(this).addClass('block--left-item').addClass('link-1');
      $('.block--left-item a').addClass('link-1').addClass(randomClassname1);
      $('.logo-svg').removeClass().addClass(randomClassname1 + ' logo-svg');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('link-2')) {
      $('.block--left-item').removeClass();
      $('.block--left-list a').removeClass();

      const randomClassname2 = randClass2();
      $(this).addClass('block--left-item').addClass('link-2');
      $('.block--left-item a').addClass('link-2').addClass(randomClassname2);
      $('.logo-svg').removeClass().addClass(randomClassname2 + ' logo-svg');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('link-3')) {
      $('.block--left-item').removeClass();
      $('.block--left-list a').removeClass();

      const randomClassname3 = randClass3();
      $(this).addClass('block--left-item').addClass('link-3');
      $('.block--left-item a').addClass('link-3').addClass(randomClassname3);
      $('.logo-svg').removeClass().addClass(randomClassname3 + ' logo-svg');
    }
  });
});


//Функция рандомного класса из массива

function randClass1() {
  let randomClass1 = colorsClass1[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsClass1.length)];
  return randomClass1;
};

function randClass2() {
  let randomClass2 = colorsClass2[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsClass2.length)];
  return randomClass2;
};

function randClass3() {
  let randomClass3 = colorsClass3[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsClass3.length)];
  return randomClass3;
};
```

```css
body, ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

li {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1170px;
}

.block--left-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.block--left-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navigation a {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.block--left {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.swiper-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 585px;
}

.block--right {
  position: relative;
}

.block--right a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.active-black {
  color: black;
}

/* Цвета для первой ссылки*/

.active-green {
  color: yellowgreen;
}
.active-blue {
  color: aqua;
}
.active-violet {
  color: darkmagenta;
}

.logo-svg.active-green {
  fill: yellowgreen;
}
.logo-svg.active-blue {
  fill: aqua;
}
.logo-svg.active-violet {
  fill: darkmagenta;
}

/* Цвета для второй ссылки*/

.active-crimson {
  color: crimson;
}
.active-magenta {
  color: magenta;
}
.active-navy {
  color: navy;
}

.logo-svg.active-crimson {
  fill: crimson;
}
.logo-svg.active-magenta {
  fill: magenta;
}
.logo-svg.active-navy {
  fill: navy;
}

/* Цвета для третьей ссылки*/

.active-coral {
  color: coral;
}
.active-chartreuse {
  color: chartreuse;
}
.active-teal {
  color: teal;
}

.logo-svg.active-coral {
  fill: coral;
}
.logo-svg.active-chartreuse {
  fill: chartreuse;
}
.logo-svg.active-teal {
  fill: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation">
        <ul class="block--left-list">
          <li class="block--left-item link-1">
            <a href="#">отделка</a>
          </li>
          <li class="block--left-item link-2">
            <a href="#">архитектура</a>
          </li>
          <li class="block--left-item link-3">
            <a href="#">планировки</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```